# What set do you get if you close the rational numbers under exponentiation?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponentiation

The rational numbers are closed under addition and multiplication, with inverses for both. But what happens if you introduce exponentiation and ask for closure under it? I know there isn't a meaningful inverse, and that you immediately expand into the irrationals and complex numbers, but do you get all the complex numbers? If yes, how can you show this? If not, has this subset of the complex plane been studied?

Edit 1: I don't mean only taking rational numbers to rational number powers, I mean you start with rationals to rational powers, but then can use any resulting numbers as base or exponent.

Edit 2: Upon reflection I am pretty sure that because you start with a countably infinite set, and you only insist on closure under an operation applied at most a finite number of times, the resulting set will only be countably infinite. So it cannot cover the complex plane.

Edit 3: Karl pointed out that exponentiation isn't always single-valued, so in any case where there multiple solutions, we could insist that all are contained in the closure set.

Comment: You might be interested in the [field of constructible numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number), which is the closure of the rationals under exponentiation by a restricted collection of rational number powers, namely those with an exponent of the form $\frac{m}{2^n}$.

Comment: You might also want to think more carefully about how you define [exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Non-integer_powers_of_complex_numbers), since it's not a continuous single-valued binary operation like addition and multiplication.

Comment: Thanks Karl, I've added that in an edit.

Comment: Note this will be bigger than the "solvable closure" $\Bbb Q^{\rm solv}$, i.e. maximal solvable extension of $\Bbb Q$, since the latter is algebraic and doesn't contain transcendentals like $2^{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: look at the paper by Chow " What is a closed-form number"; the arxiv version is https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9805045 and the published one is in AMM as I think that comes close to answering your question

Comment: I don't know enough to fully understand what is being said [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100717/zf-the-reals-are-the-countable-union-of-countable-sets-consistent), but the conclusion seems to be that without the axiom of choice, the real numbers can be seen as a countable union of countable sets, but I believe in your case AC is not needed if you cleverly choose your enumerations for each stage in the construction, but just mentioning it since there seemed to be uncertainty about your second edit